# Printing labels in Datamax printer with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, printing

Someone knows if is it possible to print a label in Datamax printer using asp.net web application with C#?
If it is possible how can it be done?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean - print from where ? from the client web browser, you can print as page - and take care if possible the correct positions and margins.

Comment: I did this, and it was ok. But I need to print a lot of labels and not just one per time.

Comment: I think you have to login to their website and Download their SDK that you will be able to add to your C# projects and interact with Datamax printers